# Restricting Duplicate results in php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

While selecting rows the data should be shown as:

[image: do]

but on the running code it is as:

[image: o]

My Codes:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "trial");
if(!$link){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$term = 'd';//mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['term']);
if(isset($term)){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM rolls WHERE Place LIKE '%" . $term . "%'";
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1000){    
        echo "<p>There are many results please be more specific</p>";
        }
        else{
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<p><a href='#". $row['Place'] ."'>" . $row['Place'] . "</a></p>";
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        }       else{
            echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
        }
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

**On trying**

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM rolls WHERE Place LIKE '%" . $term . "%' LIMIT 1";

it only displays **MANDYA**, rest all are skipped

Comment: Please describe your problem. Question heading only not helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh is this now helpful.

Comment: Try group by in query.

Comment: In your picture you said records are repeating and at then of the question you said:- `but it only displays MANDYA, rest all are skipped`. which one is true?

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh that is on trying `$sql = "SELECT * FROM rolls WHERE Place LIKE '%" . $term . "%' LIMIT 1";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display the place, use DISTINCT for showing unique values. Check out this query.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(Place) FROM rolls WHERE Place LIKE '%" . $term . "%'";
```